# Why is this Regex result unexpected

Tags: ruby, regex

The regex in question is

```
/(<iframe.*?><\/iframe>)/
```

I am using this ruby regex to match sections of a string then creating an array of the results.

The string is

```
"<p><iframe src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/k18WBkRTMldXzB7JYW5?logo=0&#038;info=0\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" width=\"580\"></iframe></p>\n<p>#1<br />\n<iframe src=\"https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id=cabe5d3ba31da\" allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"420\" width=\"640\"></iframe></p>\n<p>#2<br />\n<iframe src=\"https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id=b03d31e4b5663\" allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"420\" width=\"640\"></iframe></p>\n<p>#3<br />\n<iframe src=\"https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id=f63895add1aac\" allowfullscreen=\"\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"420\" width=\"640\"></iframe></p>\n"
```

I am calling the regex is `.match()` like so

```
/(<iframe.*?><\/iframe>)/.match(entry.content).to_a
```

The result is a duplicate of the first match

```
["<iframe src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/k18WBkRTMldXzB7JYW5?logo=0&#038;info=0\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" width=\"580\"></iframe>", "<iframe src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/k18WBkRTMldXzB7JYW5?logo=0&#038;info=0\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" width=\"580\"></iframe>"]
```

I used Rubular and I was able to get the Regex to work there http://rubular.com/r/CYF0vgQtrX

Comment: Why are you trying to parse HTML with regexes?

Comment: It was the first approach I thought of. If this wasn't going to work, then I was going to use nokogiri

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/580412

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The result is a duplicate of the first match

Even though the docs for Regex#match() do a horrible job of describing what match() does, it actually finds the *first* match:

```
str = "abc"
md = /./.match(str)
p md.to_a

--output:--
["a"]
```

Regexp.match() returns a MatchData object when there is a match.  A MatchData object contains matches for the whole match and for each group.  If you call to_a() on a MatchData object, the return value is an Array containing the whole match and whatever matched each group in the regex:

```
str = "abc"
md = /(.)(.)(.)/.match(str)
p md.to_a

--output:--
["abc", "a", "b", "c"]
```

Because you specified a group in your regex, one result is the whole match, and the other result is what matched your group.

> [A regex] was the first approach I thought of. If this wasn't going to
>   work, then I was going to use nokogiri

From now on, nokogiri should be your first thought...because:

> If you have a programming problem, and you think, "I'll use a regex",
>   now you have two problems".

Answer (score 1):

You should use `scan` instead of `match` here.

```
entry.content.scan(/<iframe.*?><\/iframe>/)
```

Using `/(<iframe.*?><\/iframe>)/` will get a 2d array. The document says:

> If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

Comment: Thanks it works. Whats your reasoning for using scan? Why wasn't `match` working? Also `scan` creates a 2d array instead of an array of strings. I used `flatten` but know of any other way around that.